# Looking for the name of "if everyone is x, no one is x"

Tags: reference-request, terminology, argumentation, identity

Usually when I browse this forum, I see many people ask for the names of fallacies. Currently, I'm looking for the name of the philosophical position that goes something like, "if everyone is x, then no one is x", "there is no x, if everyone is x". This isn't a fallacy, but I know that many fallacies have names, and I'm looking for the name of this argument, Thanks.

Comment: My best guess is that this is an example of “hasty generalization”.

Comment: I've seen it used in situations where x is a relative term like "rich". If everyone is rich, no one is rich. This is not a fallacy because it is not an argument. It is non-literal speech commenting on a contrast of perspectives. For example, practically everyone in the United States is rich by the standards of world history, but by the standards of the US today, very few of them are rich.